# Table Scan with WHERE clause (MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the following query on the MyTable table which has no indexes. There's approx. 100,000 rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

As expected I see from the execution plan that a Table Scan was performed. This takes around 3000ms.

Next I use the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE field = 'Y'
```

As expected I see from the execution plan that a Table Scan was performed. This time it takes just a fraction of that time (very few rows with field = 'Y').

Why is the second query quicker?

If the data isn't ordered surely the entire table needs to be scanned thus it should still take the 3000ms?

Thoughts:
1. Is the second query drawing off statistics collated when we ran the first query?
2. Is the majority of that 3000ms for displaying the data rather than actually querying the table?

Further:

Time Output from the first query:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(134672 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 3464 ms.
```

Time Output from the second query:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1772 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 123 ms.
```

From doing a little research, I can ignore the first part (prior to row(s) affected) as this relates to the derivation of a suitable query plan.

In the 'SQL Server Execution Times:' section, the CPU time is the part that relates to how long it took to actually query the table, correct? So why is this substantially quicker in the second query if they're both performing a table scan?

Comment: The second query is faster because it returns fewer rows.  There is overhead to returning rows, as well as reading the table.  In addition, the query may also be taking advantage of a warm cache -- meaning that the data was already loaded into memory and doesn't need to be read again.

Comment: Please see 'Further' update in the question.

Comment: Does not change the answer Gordon provided, which is correct.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret Gordon's answer. If the data was cached after running the first query, then wouldn't the first query be quicker every time I ran it? If I run the first query several times it always returns the same results give or take a few ms, as does the second query.

Further, if the 'elapsed time' part covers the visualisation and the 'CPU time' covers the scan (which should be full table in both queries), then the CPU time can't be less in the second query as a consequence of the overhead of returning rows.